# URL masking force.com-sites/sites.com

Tags: force.com-sites, custom-url, urlrewriter

We have a app in place that uses sites.com
these are the URL's that we are using

```
http://myAppURL.force.com/login
http://myAppURL.force.com/logout
http://myAppURL.force.com/refresh
http://myAppURL.force.com/register
http://myAppURL.force.com/app
```

is there a way we can mask **http://myAppURL.force.com** with **http://CustomSitesURL.com**

any help will be great.

P.S we do not wish to use iframe in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is how we solved it
Go to domain manager (in our case godaddy) add a domain point the cname to http://myAppURL.force.com

for instance http://myAppURL.force.com points to login.domain.com

On salesforce
Go to domain management and add this url there !

Now go to sites and the site you want to mask the url for

Click on the button "new custom URl" and click on the lookup for domain

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can, I've not done it yet but if you have access to change the CNAME you should be able to.

I think these are the steps:

Register a Custom Domain:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_mgmt_add.htm&language=en_US

Adding a Custom URL:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_url_add.htm&language=en_US

This is specific to site.com but also may be helpful:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_domains.htm&language=en

> You can map your standard company URL to your Force.com Sites Domain
>   Name with a 3rd-party domain name registrar. Use the Custom Web
>   Address field to set the alias to your Force.com address. To enable a
>   custom Web address, create a CNAME record with a registrar like
>   Network Solutions or Go Daddy. The CNAME record that you provide to
>   that registrar must be your Force.com domain name and not the site
>   URL. For example, if you entered "mycompany" when registering your
>   Force.com domain, the CNAME must be mycompany.force.com, not the full
>   value of the site URL. If you have not registered this address with a
>   registrar, entering a value in the Custom Web Address field has no
>   effect.

Taken from:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Sites_Best_Practices

Answer (score 0):

came across this question about an year later. Just wanted to suggest that you can also use the **Site.UrlRewriter** interface to clean them up.

Hope that helps.