# URL Masking our site.force.com URL with our Corporate Branded URL?

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-community, community-builder, custom-domain, custom-url

We have a ligthning community created using Community Builder.

We are trying to mask the URL (https://unfriendlyUrl.force.com/path) with our own corporate URL (https://community.corpsite.com).

I have been following this salesforce help documentation, as well as various posts on the Salesforce dev forum and Salesforce Stack Exchange, but have not found a definitive answer on if this is possible or not.

**Here is the official SFDC documentation:**

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_domains.htm&language=en_US

---

**Some Other Links I read (Stack Exchange and Dev Forums):**

> **Force.com site - URL masking:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ls0IAA

> **URL masking of domain name for sites:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AWevIAG

> **URL masking force.com-sites/sites.com:**

[URL masking force.com-sites/sites.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84259/url-masking-force-com-sites-sites-com)

---

> **So far this is what we've done:**
>
> 1. We created a **CNAME** subdomain on our corporate website, lets call it
>      `community.corpsite.com`.
> 2. We pointed that **CNAME** to `community.corpsite.com.OUR-18-DIGIT-ORGID.live.siteforce.com` as
>      instructed in the guide (linked above)
> 3. We went to **Site Configuration | Domains** in **Set​up** and created `community.corpsite.com` as a domain.
> 4. We went to **Site.com Studio, Site Configuration | Domains** and made sure that the custom domain (`community.corpsite.com`) was listed.
> 5. We published the site through both Site.com Studio AND Community Builder

---

When I go to my browser and go to `community.corpsite.com`, it redirects me to `https://unfriendlyUrl.force.com/path`, but doesn't mask the URL. This results in our customers having a poor branding experience, since we ask them to go to `community.corpsite.com` but they are landing at the force.com URL.

What am I doing wrong? From what I read online in their documentation, they seem to indicate that this is possible, but I can't get it to work. Is this possible? Where do I start, what is my best place for documentation on this?

Could use some help, been struggling with this all day. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have it set as the primary domain? Even if it's listed , it needs to be set as the primary.

Comment: Also check your cert chain. If there is a break in the cert chain, it will default back to the force.com one.

Comment: @cricketlang It was not set as the primary domain, so I just enabled that. No change as of yet. I'm not 100% sure how to check my cert chain, but I presume that you mean that we need a valid CA issued SSL sert for our custom domain installed into Salesforce and linked to our Custom Domain within SFDC so that we can do https to `community.corpsite.com` and be masked to the secure force.com site? If our SSL is invalid, non-existent, or has a broken link, then it automatically falls back to force.com instead of masking. Is that about right?

Comment: 100% right. Make sure your cert chain doesn't include the parent signing authority. You want the chain to be everything underneath it. Salesforce then matches your parent signing authority to its list of approved signers. If your chain has the root signing authority in it, it will fail.

Comment: Oh and the primary domain change can sometimes take up to 30 minutes to replicate, so don't sweat too hard of it didn't work immediately.

Comment: Thanks @cricketlang - I'm going to have to engage with our IT department regarding the SSL Cert and Cert chain to make sure that it is setup based on these requirements and then we'll try this again. I'll direct them to this post so that they can read your comments so nothing gets lost in translation and we'll see where we can get with it. Hopefully we can figure it out soon, we're supposed to go live with this new community on 3/1.

Comment: You should be fine. Give me a second and I should be able to post up something your IT guys can just run to build the appropriate cert chain. The cert chain was the hardest part of doing all this because every one we kept trying to import included the actual trusted cert at the top. The certs on Salesforce work similarly to the way they work in Windows where there is folder of trusted root certificates on their end that you can try to import because a root can't map to another root in the full chain.

Comment: @cricketlang Based on your comments and how sure you sound, I assume you've already implemented HTTPS masking of a custom domain to a force.com site in your org? If so, I'm glad to know that this is possible and that we're just not setup correctly. Sounds like there is light at the end of this tunnel, and I would sincerely appreciate that post to help build an appropriate cert chain so I can pass that along to IT.

Comment: Yeah we have a wildcard cert with an intermediate, which is most likely what you have on your end as well. I have 2 communities I've done this with, so don't sweat over the issue too hard. If it makes you feel any better to see one working, you can go to portal.tricore.org to see it's definitely doable ;)

Comment: I feel your pain I recently just went through this process for the first time myself. It seems as if you are on the correct path though. Going to leave a link on here that was helpful for me as well. [Arcitcle](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212707&language=en_US)

Comment: You ever get this working?

Comment: I did, to the point where at least the SSL works, masks the site by CNAME, and doesn't present any errors/warnings when browsing to the page, but when I run it through an SSL checker I get a message that my cert chain is bad, which I assume is because I didn't follow all of your steps (yet), we just uploaded the plain unmodified SSL to see what it would do.

Comment: Sounds like you got the hard stuff done. Hahaha. Hopefully you're ready enough for your deadline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, so based off the comment exchange we had, I'm going to recommend a little guide to the SSL Chains as they work when trying to import them on a custom domain.

So when you look at the cert chain, most of the time you will see it with its full path. The interesting thing with this is that if you already have the root certificate on your computer and try to export the chain, it will include the trusted root cert in the chain.

[image]

After battling this problem with many tools, I ended up finding that using [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/) would make this whole process of editing the cert chain a million times easier, so i will cover using it here.

The first thing you want to do is create a new KeyStore and create it with the type of JKS. After this point, you will likely have been given, or have, a PFX of the cert chain from your cert vendor or whatever. You need to know the decryption password btw that binds the key pair. Once you have that, just import the pair into your new keystore (PS its a PKCS #12)

[image]

From here, double click on your new import and you'll probably notice that you have the root in your chain. This is a no no. What we want to do is actually remove this from the chain so that Salesforce can map the chain to THEIR trusted root.

[image]

So to remove the root from the chain, simply right click on the entry and select "Edit Certificate Chain" and then "Remove Certificate". This will remove the top most cert from the chain, which is exactly what we are looking to do.

[image]

If you double click on the entry now, you should see the root certificate out of the cert chain now (Hooray!)

[image]

From here, you just need to export out the pair and save it off so you can upload it to Salesforce to link with your domain. You can do this by right clicking on the entry, and selecting "Export" and then "Export Certificate Chain". Leave it with Head Only and X509.

[image]

Your end result should now be a CER file without the root certificate, that is now mapping to the hopefully trusted root certificate on your PC. As you can see below, mine binds to the DigiCert trusted root CA, which is one that Salesforce has on their end. For a list of all trusted CA's on the Salesforce side, take a peek [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates)

[image]

This should hopefully help you or anyone else peeking at this answer out with the SSL side of a custom domain that requires HTTPS. It looks like you have everything else taken care of as far as the setup side is concerned. If you still have any problems or questions, feel free to post a comment and I can try to help out best i can!