# Community Website Address

Tags: community, force.com-sites, url

I have a Community named www.SampleCompany.force.com

I also have a non-Salesforce website named www.SampleCompany.org that redirects to www.SampleCompany.force.com

My goal is to have our Salesforce website called www.SampleCompany.org Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t already have a branded, custom Web address, such as  **www.SampleCompany.org, create one by registering through a domain name registrar(Name cheap, godaddy etc)**. Once done you can mask your URL with your custom domain.

Below are some available resources to give you a head start.

- [Adding Domains Using CNAME Records in Site.com](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_domains.htm&type=5)
- [URL masking force.com-sites/sites.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84259/url-masking-force-com-sites-sites-com)
- [URL Masking our site.force.com URL with our Corporate Branded URL?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108915/url-masking-our-site-force-com-url-with-our-corporate-branded-url)